# Spring Batch Unit Test triggered entire batch execution

Tags: junit, spring-batch

I am implementing a new batch with spring batch.
But I am facing some issues when I tried to run junit test.

##### Problem:

I only want to test some functions inside the service class, but when I run it, the entire batch has been executed, which caused the problem..
And I've already put `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` in the property files.

##### Expectation:

Only the service object will be executed as .

Can I get some help... ;(

##### Code samples

SpringBatchApp.class:

```java
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"xxx"})
public class XXBatchApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(XXBatchApplication.class);
        application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        application.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        List<String> params = List.of(args);
        String param1 = params.get(0);
        String param2 = params.get(1);

        startBatch(param1, param2);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void startBatch(String param1, String param2){
      ...
    }

}
```

Test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = XXBatchApplication.class)
public class ThisServiceTest {

    @Test
    void XX_case_1(){
      ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me...
I put the `XXBatchApplication` in `@SpringBootTest(classes = XXBatchApplication.classs)`
Which triggered the initialization for the batch.

After I changed the annotation for the test class as below, it works now(junit runs without executing the entire batch).
Hope this could help you a bit if you face the same issue.

```java
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ThisService.class})
@ComponentScan({"necessary.package"})
public class ThisServiceTest {
  ...
}
```